# How to style an "all day event" to have it styled like any other event?

Tags: views, theming, datetime

I am on Drupal 7. Everything works fine in Calendar module, except when I add the **all day event** then the styling is changed, I wanted the same styling for all the events.

> "All day events" are created by "date_all_day" module which comes with
>   "date" module.

[image]

Comment: Found an article [How to Style An Event Calendar in Drupal 7](http://www.cmsquickstart.com/blog/style-event-calendar-drupal-7) ... Above Article Explains > A basic setup and styling process for Calendar in Drupal 7.

Comment: I saw that tutorial, it guides me how to categories the event and add the styling. But "All day events" are created by "date_all_day" module which comes with "date" module. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand it this is a CSS question. All you need to do is add styles to overwrite the color change. It is actually two different styles that need to be changed. The following code will set them back to the yellow and light grey color that is the default for the calendar module.

```
.calendar-calendar .month-view .full td.multi-day div.monthview, 
.calendar-calendar .week-view .full td.multi-day div.weekview, 
.calendar-calendar .day-view .full td.multi-day div.dayview {
  background: #ffc;
  color: #777;
}

.calendar-calendar .month-view .full td.multi-day .inner .monthview .continues, 
.calendar-calendar .month-view .full td.multi-day .inner .monthview .cutoff, 
.calendar-calendar .week-view .full td.multi-day .inner .weekview .continues, 
.calendar-calendar .week-view .full td.multi-day .inner .weekview .cutoff {
  background: #ffc;
  color: #777;
}
```